# Rust: как заменить from_secs из std::net::TcpStream на num_seconds из chrono?

Tags: rust

Для установки timeout в [suppaftp](https://docs.rs/suppaftp/latest/suppaftp/) используется стандартная реализация из [std](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/struct.Duration.html) функция **from_secs(secs: u64) -> Duration**, пример:

```
use suppaftp::FtpStream;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::time::Duration;

let stream = FtpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:21")
                       .expect("Couldn't connect to the server...");
    stream.get_ref().set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_secs(10)))
                     .expect("set_read_timeout call failed");
```

Проблема в том, что я использую (и не могу отказаться) [chrono](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.Duration.html) и у него есть функция **num_seconds(&self) -> i64**.

Соответственно если заменить на функцию chrono:

```
use chrono::{ NaiveDateTime, Duration};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use suppaftp::FtpStream;

let mut ftp_stream = FtpStream::connect(&_ip_port)
                      .expect("Couldn't connect to the server...");
ftp_stream.get_ref().set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::num_seconds(10)))
                      .expect("set_read_timeout call failed");
```

Получаем ошибку: **expected struct `std::time::Duration`, found `i64`**

Как перевести результат num_seconds в ожидаемый от from_secs ? Или можно по другому решить задачу?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужен аналог метода `std::time::Duration::from_secs`, то используйте [`chrono::Duration::seconds`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.Duration.html#method.seconds). Вот его сигнатура:

```rust
pub fn seconds(seconds: i64) -> Duration
```

Но он возвращает `chrono::Duration`, а вам нужен `std::time::Duration`. Преобразовать можно методом [`to_std`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.Duration.html#method.to_std):

```rust
use chrono::{ NaiveDateTime, Duration};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use suppaftp::FtpStream;

let mut ftp_stream = FtpStream::connect(&_ip_port)
                      .expect("Couldn't connect to the server...");
ftp_stream.get_ref().set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::seconds(10).to_std().expect("Error"))
                      .expect("set_read_timeout call failed");
```